# Tikz does not always calculate equations

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, programming, calculations

The attached code attempts to print the first letter of the English alphabet using the alphalph package and f_1 by simple arithmetic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\x {1}
\draw (0,0) node {$\alphalph{0+\x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\x {1}
\draw (0,0) node {$f_{0+\x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Despite both desired calculations being enclosed in a single bracket the first functions as expected while the second only does the substitution and does not calculate.

Why is there a difference in behavior? What can be done to ensure that equations are calculated no matter what?

Comment: TikZ doesn't calculate anything in the text part of a node. You might want to use `{$f_{\pgfmathprint{int(0+\x)}$}`. There's also `\pgfmathprintnumber` but that's a bit overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,siunitx}

\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 0} % fix # of

\usepackage{alphalph}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\x {1}
        \draw (0,0) node {$\alphalph{0+\x}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\x {1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{\x+0}
        \draw (0,0) node {$f_{\num{\j}}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think it is good education to answer if the answer is in the desired direction.